# How to make an overloading when ther is parameters of two-sided sign '=' (Array)

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make an Array class that work just like an ordinary array (through templates)
I mean let's say my array is
`char v[12]`
I want to make it possible to carry out operations in style
`v[5] = 'c'`

The code I've done up to now:

```
template <class T, int s>
class Array {

T array[s];
int max;

public:

Array() {
    T array[s];
    max = s;
}

Array operator[](int x) const {
        return array[x];
}

Array operator=(int x) const {  // this is for v[15]=20 or v[15]='c' , i don't know how to do it

}

};
```

my main looks like this:

```
//this 2 lines works good (creates 2 array 1 int and 1 char)
Array <int, 50> int_array;
Array <char, 50> char_array;

  //i want to make this option possible
  /*
      int_array[12]=30;
      char_array[8]='l';
      cout<<int_array[12]<<' '<<char_array[8]<<endl;
   */
```

I've overloaded the [] sign so it will be possible to do v[12] , but now I have a problem, how do I load = in a way I can make placement of what the in the right of the = sign  into the correct position in the array.
(It must be  with a template so it will support all kinds of types(int,char,float,etc.))

Comment: In your constructor you define a *local* variable `array`, that iwll go out of scope when the constructor returns. That local variable is unrelated to the member variable.

Comment: As for your problem, the `[]` operator function returns an element of the array, not an instance of the `Array` class. Also think about *references* and how they can be used.